# Concatenate variables as commands in bash

Tags: android, bash, shell, variables, concatenation

I want to declare character variables and then write those variables one after the other in order to form a command. Example:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
tt=e;rr=c;uu=h;yy=o; 
zz=i;ll=f;pp=n;cc=t

x=29
$zz$ll [ "$x"-eq 29 ]
$cc$uu$tt$pp
$tt$rr$uu$yy "yes"
$ll$zz
```

This code should read:

```
if [ "$x" -eq 29 ]
then
echo "yes"
fi
```

This works for the "echo" command but won't work for "if".

Always getting errors: if not found, then not found, fi not found.

I've tired surrounding with quotes and braces.

This is being done on android.

Comment: bash recognizes keywords (like `if`, `then`, etc) before expanding variables, so putting a keyword in a variable doesn't work. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (And don't be tempted by `eval` -- that way lies madness and even weirder bugs.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that i can achieve the desired outcome by utilizing the fact that echo will work regardless. so I echo the entire contents of the shell script in question (test.sh) and run commands in another bash instance reading from stdin.

Modified code now is

```
tt="e";rr="c";uu="h";yy="o";_1="i";ll="f";pp="n";cc="t"
x=29
"$1" "
$_1$ll [ "$x" -${tt}q 29 ]
$cc$uu$tt$pp
$tt$rr$uu$yy \"yes this file ran without error\"
$ll$_1
"
```

to run this:

```
/system/test.sh echo | sh -
```